# Clear char_filter from elasticsearch index settings

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I clear char_filter definition from index setting?

I have below index setting with char_filter defined and used in default analyzer.

```
GET /indexName/_settings
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "char_filter": {
                "custom_filter": {
                    "type": "mapping",
                    "mappings": [
                        "Customer@Cloud => Customer_at_Cloud"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "default": {
                    "char_filter": [
                        "custom_filter"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Clearing out the char_filter object it does not help

```
PUT /indexName/_settings
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "char_filter": null
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "default": {
                    "char_filter": [ ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to
i) overwrite the char_filter in default analyzer and set it to empty so that the char_filter is not used and also
ii)able to update custom_filter mapping to be empty.
But I want to know how do I remove custom_filter definition. I tried clearing like below but it did not work.

```
PUT /indexName/_settings
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "char_filter": {}  
            }
        }
    }
}
OR 
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "char_filter": {
                "custom_filter": { }     
            }
        }
    }
}
Response: 
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
                "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: no settings to update;"
            }
        ],
        "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
        "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: no settings to update;"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

```
PUT /indexName/_settings
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "char_filter": null 
            }
        }
    }
}
OR 
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "char_filter": {
                "custom_filter": null    
            }
        }
    }
}
Response: 
{
    "acknowledged": true
}
But in GET /indexName/_settings response, I see custom_filter definition is present.
```

I did close the index before updating the index settings. I am avoiding deleting the index and creating a new one with desired setting, which works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing something wrong while updating the setting. Here an example for you. When you try the following commands one by one. You can see it works :

```
PUT indexb
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "char_filter": {
        "custom_filter": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            "Customer@Cloud => Customer_at_Cloud"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "custom_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

GET indexb/_settings

POST indexb/_close

PUT indexb/_settings
{
  "analysis": {
    "char_filter": {
      "custom_filter": {
        "type": "mapping",
        "mappings": []
      }
    }
  }
}

POST indexb/_open

GET indexb/_settings
```

In the end, here is what we are getting on setting response :

```
{
  "indexb": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "routing": {
          "allocation": {
            "include": {
              "_tier_preference": "data_content"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_shards": "1",
        "provided_name": "indexb",
        "creation_date": "1670702801437",
        "analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "default": {
              "type": "custom",
              "char_filter": [
                "custom_filter"
              ],
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            }
          },
          "char_filter": {
            "custom_filter": {
              "type": "mapping",
              "mappings": []
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "AW14oRJKRhCe11kbxcxkuw",
        "version": {
          "created": "8050299"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Lastly, I just try with Elasticsearch 8.5.2. FYI.